# How can I get my Apache VPS server to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"?

Tags: php, apache, cors, vps, godaddy-api

I acquired a new VPS from Godaddy and have already set this property to allow cross origin in my `.htaccess` file and in the `httpd.conf`, I have set `AllowOverride All` as shown, respectively, in the code below, despite which I still get the errors that follows:

**// .htaccess**

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php83” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php83 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

AddType video/MP2T ts
AddType application/dash+xml mpd

# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    # <FilesMatch "\.(mpd)$">
    #     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    # </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

**/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf**

```
<IfModule include_module>
  <Directory "/home/indupendo/public_html">
    AllowOverride All // <-- I added this line here.
    SSILegacyExprParser On
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

**The CORS issue in browser**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://indupendo.com/be-a/public/ads/video/rapper/rapper.mpd' from origin 'https://livepush.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
hlsplayer.2397aef1.js:1 
        
        
       GET https://indupendo.com/be-a/public/ads/video/rapper/rapper.mpd net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
```

On `ssh cli`, I got this after testing the response from the link in question, which indeed shows that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not being set:

```
curl -I https://indupendo.com/be-a/public/ads/video/rapper/rapper.mpd
HTTP/2 200
last-modified: Fri, 29 Dec 2023 13:10:34 GMT
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 1397
vary: Accept-Encoding
date: Sat, 30 Dec 2023 13:45:44 GMT
server: Apache
```

How can I set this header and combat the error?

Comment: Do you have `mod_headers` enabled on your VPS?

Comment: Take your pick [from a simple search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=set+Access-Control-Allow-Origin+in+apache&t=newext&atb=v362-1&ia=web)

Comment: @esqew Oh yes! I checked on my `ssh` for this `httpd -M | grep headers_module` and got
 `headers_module (shared)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I derived my answer from @esqew and @RiggsFolly's guide above. Even though my server was saying `headers_module (shared)` upon checking on `ssh` with  `httpd -M | grep headers_module`, the jttpd.conf file did not have any `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` so below a similar one, `<IfModule mod_include.c>`, I added the `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` like so:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <Directory "/path/to/my/domain's/root/">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the header in the php file being requested if the .htaccess isn't working as expected.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
```

Feel free to add comment or support my opinion. Thanks

Comment: I do support your opinion, @Mac, as it technically makes sense, but my issue is that am not requesting a PHP file. I am rather hitting a MPEG-DASH manifest file that should allow me adaptive streaming of the file segments and variants it points to.

Comment: The go by this
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <Directory "/path/to/my/domain's/root/">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </Directory>
</IfModule>